# Why does my iCloud tabs on Mac OS X not work?

Tags: icloud, safari

I have a number of Apple devices (iPhone, iPad, Macbook and Mac Mini). I would like to use iCloud tab syncing between the devices, I have successfully enabled my macbook, iPhone and iPad but I'm unable to get it working on my Mac mini.

I can confirm the settings are all switched on but the tabs are still not visible in Safari.
Anyone have any suggestions to fix this?

All devices are using the latest available software (iOS and Mac OSX)

Answer (score 1):

Sign out and sign back into iCloud on your Mac.

There was also a bug that if you had iCloud drive turned off for safari, your tabs wouldn't sync. So I would make sure that Safari is checked under iCloud Drive as well as iCloud settings.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a website in Safari on my iPhone 5s (iOS 8.0.2) and waited a few minutes. Then I clicked the iCloud Tabs button in the toolbar of Safari on my Mac mini (late 2012, OS X 10.9.5) and noticed that it was empty. It wasn't until I clicked the home button on my iPhone (sending Safari into the background) that the iCloud tabs synced. Try opening a website in Safari on your iPhone, then click the home button and check the iCloud tabs in Safari on your Mac mini.

Comment: I've tried this, usually I have another device to test to make sure it is syncing and they all work.. It's definitely something with the Mac mini

Comment: Hmm.. I don't remember doing anything special with my Mac mini. Are you sure your Mac mini is using the same iCloud account that is being used for the rest of your devices? That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Definitely using the same iCloud account